# How to adjusting camera to be directly behind the new direction of the model?

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I have problem in moving camera behind the car.The camera can not adjusting itself to be directly behind the new direction of the car.

My code:

```
    Vector3 tmpV = new Vector3();   
    Quaternion quatRotation = new Quaternion();
    //chassis is car
    chassis.transform.getTranslation(camera.position);
    tmpV.set(camera.position).sub(5, 0, 5).y = 0f;
    chassis.transform.getRotation(quatRotation);
    camera.rotate(quatRotation);
    camera.position.add(tmpV.nor().scl(-4f)).y = 4.f;
    chassis.transform.getTranslation(tmpV);
    camera.lookAt(tmpV);
    camera.up.set(Vector3.Y);
```

It is currently happening when moving right:
[image]

What i needs to happen when moving right:
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/xoppa/world/blob/master/src/com/xoppa/android/world/ChaseCamera.java see it in action over here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alCLHywqtiI

Answer (score 0):

By using of this class from this [link](https://github.com/xoppa/world/blob/master/src/com/xoppa/android/world/ChaseCamera.java)
that Xoppa posted in the comment:

```
    camera.desiredLocation.set(new Vector3(0, 5, 5));
    camera.transform=chassis.transform;
    camera.up.set(Vector3.Y);
```